# Wordpress - save similar metabox fields into array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I need to save into array values with same keys. For example for select name 'crop43' i need to save two values: vertical and horizontal.

Input fields in metabox:

```
<p>
<label for="crop43">4:3 Crop position</label>
<select name="crop43[]" style="width: 10%">
    <option>Center</option>
    <option>Top</option>
    <option>Bottom</option>
</select>
<select name="crop43[]" style="width: 10%">
    <option>Center</option>
    <option>Left</option>
    <option>Right</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Saving procedure:

```
if(isset($_POST['crop43'])) {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'crop43', $_POST['crop43']);
}
```

It save only the last information (horizontal position), but not vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier solution is to rename the 2 selects.

```
<p>
<label for="vertical">4:3 Crop position</label>
<select name="vertical" style="width: 10%">
    <option>Center</option>
    <option>Top</option>
    <option>Bottom</option>
</select>
<select name="horizontal" style="width: 10%">
    <option>Center</option>
    <option>Left</option>
    <option>Right</option>
</select>
</p>
```

You can then do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['horizontal'] && isset($_POST['vertical]){

$array = array();
$array['horizontal'] = $_POST['horizontal'];
$array['vertical'] = $_POST['vertical'];
$crop43 = json_encode($array);

update_post_meta($post->ID, 'crop43', $crop43);

}
```

Then, use json_decode when you want to change de database value back to an array.